# Multiple bouncing balls thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

I created a program that makes multiple bouncing balls with random color, speed and radius. When user clicks on the screen a new random ball should appear and move around screen. But i have a multi-thread issue. When i click on the screen a ball appears and doesn't moving at all. When another click comes nothing happens.

*BouncingBalls Class*

```
public class BouncingBalls extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

private Ball ball;
protected List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(20);
private Container container;
private DrawCanvas canvas;
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;
public static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30;

int x = random(480);
int y = random(480);
int speedX = random(30);
int speedY = random(30);
int radius = random(20);
int red = random(255);
int green = random(255);
int blue = random(255);
int count = 0;

public static int random(int maxRange) {
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
}

public BouncingBalls(int width, int height){

    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;

    ball = new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue);
    container = new Container();

    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.addMouseListener(this);

}

public void start(){

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            while(true){

                update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

public void update(){

    ball.move(container);
}

class DrawCanvas extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        container.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){

        return(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setContentPane(new BouncingBalls(500, 500));
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    count++;
    balls.add(new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue));
    balls.get(count-1).start();
    start();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

*Ball Class*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball{

public static int random(int maxRange) {
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
}

private BouncingBalls balls;
int x = random(480);
int y = random(480);
int speedX = random(30);
int speedY = random(30);
int radius = random(20);
int red = random(255);
int green = random(255);
int blue = random(255);
int i = 0;

public Ball(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY, int radius, int red, int green, int blue){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    for(Ball ball : balls){

        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.fillOval((int)(x - radius), (int)(y - radius), (int)(2 * radius), (int)(2 * radius));
    }
}

public void move(Container container){

    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;

    if(x - radius < 0){

        speedX = -speedX;
        x = radius;
    }
    else if(x + radius > 500){

        speedX = -speedX;
        x = 500 - radius;
    }

    if(y - radius < 0){

        speedY = -speedY;
        y = radius;
    }
    else if(y + radius > 500){

        speedY = -speedY;
        y = 500 - radius;
    }
}
}
```

*Container Class*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Container {

private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
private static final int WIDTH = 500;
private static final Color COLOR = Color.WHITE;

public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(COLOR);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
}
```

Comment: First question before I read the code - why do you need multiple threads.  Two should do, the Event Dispatching Thread (which Swing provides) and your animation/update thread...?

Comment: Don't i need to multiple threads to move multiple balls?

Comment: Yes, but not a thread per ball (which is how your question reads to me) - you only need an animation thread to actually update then repaint the balls...

Comment: Hmm i get your point. I was trying to create a thread for every ball. How can i do an animation thread?

Comment: @MadProgrammer But its easier to keep one thread per ball and then each thread sleeps a fixed amount and then moves and draws its ball. He doesn't have but one extra thread but making each ball a Runnable should help with that if the click that builds the Ball object starts it too.

Comment: An animation thread would wait the requisite time and then move and redraw all the balls. A click would just add a ball to the list and it would appear when the animation thread next draws. Threadsafety would be an issue as the click thread adds the new Ball to the list and the animation thread might be moving it at the same time.

Comment: Does anyone remember if an ArrayList is threadsafe?

Comment: @LeeMeador No, a `ArrayList` is not thread safe, `Vector` is.  Seen as you're not removing items, it may not be a MASSIVE issue, but one worth fixing any way.  As to one/many threads.  I think you will find that a single thread would be easier to manage, be more capable of maintaining a given frame-rate and use less resources...IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sure, I knew that one 10 years ago. How quickly we forget. It sort of depends on whether OP is trying to learn about threads and how to manage a bunch of them or trying to make an efficient and smooth animation engine.

Comment: @LeeMeador True.  Maybe you could provide an example of a multiple threaded solution as a comparison? :D - Seriously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're maintaing two different references to your ball.

You have a reference to a single `Ball` called `ball` and a `List` of balls.  Your `update` and `paint` methods only reference the single `ball`

`Ball` doesn't seem to have a `start` method (that I can see) so this `balls.get(count-1).start();` doesn't make sense...

**Updated**

- You don't need the reference to `ball`
- While not a bad idea, while testing, you should probably call `start` in the constructor
- Your `update` method in `BouncingBalls` should looping through the `balls` list, calling `move` on each ball in the list...
- The `paintComponent` method of `DrawCanvas` needs access to and should make use of the `balls` list.  This might be better achievable through a model interface
- Do not construct a new `Ball` with parameters, as it's giving each ball the same properties, especially when you assign random values to it when you construct it any way...
- `Ball` doesn't have (or need) a `start` method

[image]

```
public class BouncingBalls extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

//    private Ball ball;
    protected List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(20);
    private Container container;
    private DrawCanvas canvas;
    private int canvasWidth;
    private int canvasHeight;
    public static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30;
    int x = random(480);
    int y = random(480);
    int speedX = random(30);
    int speedY = random(30);
    int radius = random(20);
    int red = random(255);
    int green = random(255);
    int blue = random(255);
    int count = 0;

    public static int random(int maxRange) {
        return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
    }

    public BouncingBalls(int width, int height) {

        canvasWidth = width;
        canvasHeight = height;

//        ball = new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue);
        container = new Container();

        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        start();

    }

    public void start() {

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                while (true) {

                    update();
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    public void update() {
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.move(container);
        }
    }

    class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            container.draw(g);
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                ball.draw(g);
            }
//            ball.draw(g);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            return (new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(new BouncingBalls(500, 500));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        count++;
        balls.add(new Ball());
//        balls.add(new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue));
//        balls.get(count - 1).start();
//        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static class Ball {

        public int random(int maxRange) {
            return (int) Math.round(Math.random() * maxRange);
        }
        int x = random(480);
        int y = random(480);
        int speedX = random(30);
        int speedY = random(30);
        int radius = random(20);
        int red = random(255);
        int green = random(255);
        int blue = random(255);
        int i = 0;

        public Ball() { //int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY, int radius, int red, int green, int blue) {

//            this.x = x;
//            this.y = y;
//            this.speedX = speedX;
//            this.speedY = speedY;
//            this.radius = radius;
//            this.red = red;
//            this.green = green;
//            this.blue = blue;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
            g.fillOval((int) (x - radius), (int) (y - radius), (int) (2 * radius), (int) (2 * radius));

        }

        public void move(Container container) {

            x += speedX;
            y += speedY;

            if (x - radius < 0) {

                speedX = -speedX;
                x = radius;
            } else if (x + radius > 500) {

                speedX = -speedX;
                x = 500 - radius;
            }

            if (y - radius < 0) {

                speedY = -speedY;
                y = radius;
            } else if (y + radius > 500) {

                speedY = -speedY;
                y = 500 - radius;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Container {

        private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
        private static final int WIDTH = 500;
        private static final Color COLOR = Color.WHITE;

        public void draw(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(COLOR);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**

As pointed out by the commentators, `ArrayList` is not thread safe, it's not a good idea to have multiple threads trying to access it simultaneously.  While adding is slightly safer then removing, it is still bad practice.

You can either replace `ArrayList` with `Vector`, which would be the simpler solution, or synchronize the access to the list around a common monitor lock.  Given your example, I'd use a `java.util.Vector`

Comment: You don't have to be insane, but crazy helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this alternate Java Programm for bouncing 10 multi-colored balls on a single "START" button.....

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javaimage.io.*;

class Thr extends Thread
{
    boolean up=false;
    Ballbounce parent;
    int top,left;
    Color c;

    Thr(int t,int l,Color cr,ex5 p)
    {
        top=l;
        if(top > 170)
        top=170-t/8;
        left=t;
        c=cr;
        parent=p;
    }

    public void run()
    {
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(37);
            if(top >= 188)
            up=true;
            if(top <= 0)
            up=false;
            if(!up)
            top=top+2;
            else
            top=top-2;
            parent.p.repaint();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
}

    class Ballbounce extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
int top=0,left=0,n=0,radius=50;
Color C[]={Color.black,Color.cyan,Color.orange,Color.red,Color.yellow,Color.pink,Color.gray,Color.blue,Color.green,Color.magenta};
Thr t[]=new Thr[10];
GPanel p;
JButton b;
Panel  p1;

Ballbounce()
{
setSize(700,300);
setVisible(true);
setLayout( new BorderLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
add(p=new GPanel(this),BorderLayout.CENTER);

b= new JButton("Start");
b.addActionListener(this);


add(p1=new Panel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
p1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
p1.add(b);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
new Ballbounce();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
t[n]=new Thr(left+(radius+13)*n+29,top+n*25,C[n],this);
t[n].start();
n++;
p.repaint();
if(n >9)
b.setEnabled(false);
}
}

class GPanel extends JPanel
{
Ballbounce parent;

GPanel(Ballbounce p)
{
 parent=p;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);
setBackground(Color.white);

for(int i=0;i< parent.n;i++)
{
g.setColor(parent.t[i].c);
g.fillOval(parent.t[i].left,parent.t[i].top,parent.radius,parent.radius);
}
}
}
```

I hope you will like it.... 
If u are unable to understand the code... You can question it anytime...... :)
Enjoy the code... :)