# Smooth out Java paint animations

Tags: java, multithreading, repaint

I would like to make my app draw moving image a little smoother than how it is currently drawing them. I am not sure what to do to do that.

This is what my main game Thread looks like:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    int delay = 500; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            Car car = new Car();
            int speed = (int)(3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 3)));
            car.setSpeed(speed);
            MainLoop.this.gameObjects.vehicles.add(car.create("/Media/Graphics/blueCar.png", width - 20, 78));
            car.driveTo(0, 78);
        }
    };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
    try{
        while(true){
            this.repaint();
            for(GameObject go : this.gameObjects.vehicles){
                // loops through objects to move them
                Vehicle vh = (Vehicle) go;
                this.moveVehicle(vh);
                if(vh.getX() <= vh.getDestX()){
                    vh.markForDeletion(true);
                }
            }
            this.gameObjects.destroyVehicles();
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a method that calculates the items next x/y position

```
protected void moveVehicle(Vehicle vh){
    int cx = vh.getX();
    int dx = vh.getDestX();
    int cy = vh.getY();
    int dy = vh.getDestY();
    // move along x axis
    // getMaxSpeed() = Number between 3 and 6
    if(cx > dx && vh.movingX() == -1){
        vh.setX(cx - vh.getMaxSpeed());
    }else if(cx < dx && vh.movingX() == 1){
        vh.setX(cx + vh.getMaxSpeed());
    }else{
        vh.setX(dx);
    }

    // move along y axis
    // getMaxSpeed() = Number between 3 and 6
    if(cy > dy && vh.movingY() == -1){
        vh.setY(cy - vh.getMaxSpeed());
    }else if(cy < dy && vh.movingY() == 1){
        vh.setY(cy + vh.getMaxSpeed());
    }else{
        vh.setY(dy);
    }
}
```

This is my paint method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;

    for(GameObject go : gameObjects.vehicles){
        g.drawImage(go.getSprite(), go.getX(), go.getY(), this);
    }
}
```

This is possibly more info than needed, but I would like to know, what should I do to make items move from `left -> right` `top -> bottom` as smoothly as possible, without much of a performance loss?

**Edit: Requested sscce:**

```
package sscce;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Sscce extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sscce(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(this);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Sscce();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int delay = 500; //milliseconds
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                Square squ = new Square();
                Sscce.this.squares.add(squ);
                squ.moveTo(0);
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
        while(true){
            try{
                for(Square s : this.squares){
                    int objX = s.getX();
                    int desX = s.getDestX();
                    if(objX <= desX){
                        System.out.println("removing");
                        this.squares.remove(s);
                    }else{
                        s.setX(s.getX() - 10);
                    }
                }
                this.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(Square s : squares){
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(s.getX(), s.getY(), 50, 50);
        }
    }
}

class Square{

    public int x = 0, y = 0, destX = 0;

    public Square(){
        this.x = 400;
        this.y = 100;
    }

    public void moveTo(int destX){
        this.destX = destX;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getDestX(){
        return this.destX;
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540534/how-to-make-line-animation-smoother/13547895#13547895) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593678/multiple-bouncing-balls-thread-issue/14593761#14593761) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642852/the-images-are-not-loading/12648265#12648265) (just because I like it)

Comment: Lets start with, without a working example, it's not going to be possible to help you. But lets start with how pointless Thread.sleep(1); this is. And then go on to mention that it's possible for Swing to perform a repaint while you're updating the model

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added an sscce. If I don't put `Thread.sleep(1);` nothing gets drawn.

Comment: The problem with `Thread.sleep(1)` it's as close to `Thread.sleep(0)` as makes no difference.  Trying to generate a progress bar?

Comment: The other problem with `Thread.sleep(1)` is that most people aren't even going to be able to see a difference. Roughly speaking, 25fps a second is more the sufficient (about 40 milliseconds).  The problem revolves around the distance change more then the number of updates...

Comment: I figured it was a distance thing, but do you know of a way to make it as smooth as possible from going from point **A** to point **B**?

Comment: It depends.  Any animation is an illusion.  To slow and it won't like right, to fast and will stagger

Answer (score 1):

First note, for some reason, I had issues with the `JPanel` implementing `Runnable` when running it under MacOS - I have no idea why, but that's why I moved it out.

It is possible for your `squares` to be update while it is been used to paint which will cause an exception (also, removing elements from a list while you're iterating it isn't a good idea either ;))

Instead, I have two lists.  I have a model, which the list can modify and then the paint list which the `paint` method can use.  This allows the thread to modifiy the model, while a paint process is underway.

To prevent any clash, I've added in a lock, which prevents one thread from modifying/accessing the paint list, while another thread has it locked.

Now.  Down to the real problem.  The main issue you're having isn't the amount of time between the updates, but the distance you are moving.  Reduce the distance (to make it slower) and standarise the updates.

Most people won't notice anything much over 25fps, so trying to do much more then that is just wasting CPU cycles and starving the repaint manager, preventing it from actually updating the screen.

It's a balancing act to be sure...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestAnimation11 extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    private ReentrantLock lock;

    public TestAnimation11() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.add(TestAnimation11.this);
                Thread t = new Thread(new UpdateEngine());
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestAnimation11();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Square[] paint = null;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            paint = squares.toArray(new Square[squares.size()]);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        for (Square s : paint) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(s.getX(), s.getY(), 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public class UpdateEngine implements Runnable {

        private List<Square> model = new ArrayList<>(squares);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int ticks = 0;
            List<Square> dispose = new ArrayList<>(25);
            while (true) {
                ticks++;
                dispose.clear();
                for (Square s : model) {
                    int objX = s.getX();
                    int desX = s.getDestX();
                    if (objX <= desX) {
                        dispose.add(s);
                    } else {
                        s.setX(s.getX() - 2);
                    }
                }
                model.removeAll(dispose);
                if (ticks == 11) {
                    Square sqr = new Square();
                    sqr.moveTo(0);
                    model.add(sqr);
                } else if (ticks >= 25) {
                    ticks = 0;
                }
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    squares.clear();
                    squares.addAll(model);
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Square {

        public int x = 0, y = 0, destX = 0;

        public Square() {
            this.x = 400;
            this.y = 100;
        }

        public void moveTo(int destX) {
            this.destX = destX;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return this.x;
        }

        public int getDestX() {
            return this.destX;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return this.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this a little later!