# adding squares to an animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt

1. I'm trying to create a program that runs an animation similar to the one on [this video](http://vimeo.com/36278748) but I'm having trouble adding more squares. I tried to add all the squares to an array list but I couldn't figure out where it goes.
2. so far this is my code:

   ```
   public class Animation extends JFrame{

   CrazySquares square = new CrazySquares();

   Animation(){

   add(new CrazySquares());
   }

   public static void main (String[] args){

   Animation frame = new  Animation();
   frame.setTitle("AnimationDemo");
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(250, 250);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   }

   class CrazySquares extends JPanel{


   private final int numberOfRectangles=100;

       Color color=new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256));

        private int x=1;
          private int y=1;
       private Timer timer = new Timer(30, new TimerListener());
      Random random= new Random();
           int randomNumber=1+(random.nextInt(4)-2);

    Random rand= new Random();
    int rando=1+(rand.nextInt(4)-2);          


      CrazySquares(){
           timer.start();

      }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);

    int width=getWidth();
    int height=getHeight();


             g.setColor(color);
   g.fillRect(x+width/2,y+(int)(height*.47), 20, 20);


    }


     class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       x += rando;
       y+= randomNumber;
          repaint();

        }


   }

   }
   ```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593678/multiple-bouncing-balls-thread-issue/14593761#14593761) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642852/the-images-are-not-loading/12648265#12648265) and if you're feeling really brave, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184) which demonstrates pretty much the basic idea you are trying to achieve...

Comment: thaks guys.
 I need to know how to add multiple squares

Answer (score 1):

You've got code to paint out one rectangle, here:

```
int width=getWidth();
int height=getHeight();

g.setColor(color);
g.fillRect(x+width/2,y+(int)(height*.47), 20, 20);
```

Now what I would recommend, would be that you port these values into a `Square` object. Or, better yet, use the `Rectangle` object. If you went with the custom approach:

```
public class Square
{
     public Square(int x, int y, int height, int width)
     {
         // Store these values in some fields.
     }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
         g.fillRect() // Your code for painting out squares. 
     }
}
```

Then, all you need to do, is call each object's `paintComponent` method in some list. Let's assume you have some List:

```
List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();


for(Square sq : squares)
{
    sq.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: where should i put the list?

Comment: in the `CrazySquares` class I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code so far. I know its nasty but its because i've been trying different things a none of them work. i really appreciate your help. thanks. @ChrisCooney

```
 public class SquaresAnimation extends JFrame{
  SquaresAnimation(){
      add(new CrazySquares());



}

public static void main (String[] args){
 SquaresAnimation frame = new  SquaresAnimation();
frame.setTitle("AnimationDemo");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 }

 class Square{
 private int x;
 private int y;
 public int height;
 public int width;




  Square(int x, int y, int height, int width)
 {
     // Store these values in some fields.
     this.x=x;
     this.y=y;
     this.height=height;
     this.width=width;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(x+width/2,y+(int)(height*.47), 20, 20); 
 }
}

class CrazySquares extends JPanel {



 private final int numberOfRectangles=100;

 Color color=new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256));

  private int x=1;
    private int y=1;
 Random random= new Random();
     int randomNumber=1+(random.nextInt(4)-2);

     Random rand= new Random();
     int rando=1+(rand.nextInt(4)-2);

     private Timer timer = new Timer(30, new TimerListener());

     List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();


      CrazySquares(Graphics g){
    timer.start();

  for(Square sq : squares){

sq.paintComponent(g);
}


    }

}

//protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//super.paintComponent(g);      

 //         }

 class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    repaint();

  }

    }
```